# exporting multicolumn listbox to specific range

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

background info: I have a userform, which contain a 2-column listbox and a command button

I want to export all items in listbox (from both column) into a sheet through the button. I am thinking of using loop to get all of the information from the listbox, but somehow it is not working. When run, it gives me only the first row from the listbox, but not the other rows.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i, t As Double
Dim inputrow As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set sh = Sheets("sheet1")

lastrow = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

i = ListBox2.ListCount

For inputrow = lastrow To lastrow + i

    For t = 0 To i
    
        sh.Range("A" & inputrow).Value = ListBox2.List(t, 0)
        sh.Range("B" & inputrow).Value = ListBox2.List(t, 1)
            
    Exit For
     
    Next t

Exit For

Next inputrow

end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following sub.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
lRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Range("A" & lRow)
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        Rng.Offset(i + 1, 0) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 0)
        'sh.Range("A" & lRow + i + 1) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 0)
        
        Rng.Offset(i + 1, 1) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 1)
        'sh.Range("B" & lRow + i + 1) = Me.ListBox1.List(i, 0)
    Next i

Set Rng = Nothing
Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```